# Weasyprint or Reportlab for generating Django reports on Heroku

Tags: python, django, heroku, reportlab, weasyprint

Trying to decide on the best route for generating server-side pdf reports within my app currently deployed on Heroku. I've read several posts that say both require installation external libraries- but haven't found anything describing functionality & ease of install on Heroku.

Does anyone here have experience installing either to an app on Heroku? Is it a difficult process- is one easier to setup on Heroku than the other? Or if I am able to install on my local system and run PIP Freeze, will that take care of any installs necessary on Heroku?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have foremost experience of Reportlab. To get it up and running requires quite lot of effort from your side, it does not work "out of the box" and involves lot of programming (you need to create templates, build logic around text, build routines around batch jobs etc.). It installs as a normal PIP package, but then you need to start programming to get it working.

However, it looks like Weasyprint uses another technology to generate pdf (CSS for print) which might be a more readily accessible solution if you already have pages formatted with CSS.

Comment: Thanks for the insight! I think I will start with Weasyprint and possibly grow to ReportLab in the future then. thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Weasyprint needs some dependencies installed, think it's not possible to install it on heroku. I tested it locally and it worked pretty well, after the setup was done, it was easy to feed a nice dynamic html-document and get a solid pdf in return.

heroku offers a web2pdf-addon: 
https://elements.heroku.com/addons/webtopdf#details

I did not test it yet, but it looks promising.

Answer (score 3):

I have just added **WeasyPrint** to my **Django** program. I tested it both locally and on **Heroku**. It worked very nicely on both places.

If you are using Django, you can first run pip3 freeze to get the right WeasyPrint information (version) to use in your requirements file:

```
$ pip3 freeze
```

Then look for the WeasyPrint information. For me, it was the following line:

```
WeasyPrint==51
```

Add this line to the *requirements.txt* file. Then run:

```
$ git add -A
$ git commit -m "Changed requirements"
$ git push heroku master
```

Heroku adds WeasyPrint and its dependencies.

Comment: How did you install cairo, Pango and GDK-PixBuf on Heroku?

Answer (score 2):

WeasyPrint is much easier to use than ReportLab, the only issue with weasyprint is it doesn't handle page breaks correctly (since you're converting an HTML page to PDF) which can be a deal breaker if your reports extend on more than 1 page (for example tables)